# Can I use Aliases on my Postfix email server to reroute mail to my admin email address?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, ubuntu-16.04, postfix

I have an Ubuntu 16.04.2 server running Postfix 3.1.0, which I'm using as an email relay for another server running Cron jobs.

Various error emails, including bad address bounces, are being sent to www-data@mydomain.com, which doesn't have an email box. These messages are clogging up my postqueue with nowhere to go.

I've been trying to reroute these emails to me@myotherdomain.com with aliases, virtual or otherwise.

The problems I'm experiencing are:

1. I'm not sure I the way I'm testing (using sendmail: `sudo mail -s
   "test subject" www-data`) is effective.
2. I can't tell if my alias changes are being added correctly, despite using `newaliases` and `postalias hash:/etc/aliases`, as well as restarting the postfix service.
3. I'm not sure this is actually even something that can be done with aliases, as opposed to header rewrites.

My alias file:

```
# See man 5 aliases for format
postmaster:     root
```

My virtual file:

```
www-data@mydomain.com me@myotherdomain.com
```

main.cf has `alias_maps` and `alias_database` set, but not `virtual_alias_domains` or `virtual_alias_maps`. That was going to be the next thing I tried, but if it's as I said earlier that my testing is no good, it won't make a difference.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I've got this working now. Solution goes like this:

1. Create /etc/postfix/virtual, and fill it with your virtual aliases, as I did in the original question.
2. Run `postmap /etc/postfix/virtual`
3. Populate `virtual_alias_domains` and `virtual_alias_maps` in main.cf
4. Run `postfix reload`
5. Test by running a command like `mail -s "Test subject" www-data@mydomain.com <<< "Test body"`

Then you should see the message show up in the rerouted mailbox.

Any time after that if I wanted to update my virtual file, I just reran steps 2 and 4 again.

The docs page that helped me figure it out: http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html#virtual_alias (See 'Mail forwarding domains' section)